# Updating phonegap app's assets without resubmitting to store

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Updating app's assets without resubmitting to store

Is there some known solution for updating app (app's assets), so that if we want to have changes in apps logic, we would not need to resubmit app in store again?

In other words is there hydration like solution for production?

I tried to google but didn't find one.
If i'm not mistaken it is not against stores rules (app store, play store) to update the apps assets if app actually doen't change its initial purpose.

If so I wonder why there is still no known working solution?

Comment: On iOS the assets  bundled with the app are part of the signed bundle and you must resubmit if you change anything so that the bundle can be Re-signed and updated on the App Store. The only way is to download your assets the first time the app runs; then you can change your web server or whatever and have the app check for new assets

Comment: Yes I understand the tech, I wonder why no implementation yet available.

Comment: How would it work? A central part of iOS application security is that the application bundle is signed by Apple.  If you modify components of the bundle then the signature will be invalidated and the bundle needs to be re-signed.  Even if the assets were outside of the signed bundle you would still need to re-submit the updated bundle to get in on the app store

Comment: How hydration works? The second: "Even if the assets were outside of the signed bundle you would still need to re-submit.." who said that?

Comment: Because the bundle is hosted on Apple's server - so they need to put it there.  And even if they allowed you to update it without review, what happens if you decide to stick a bunch of nude photos in there - or your account is hacked and someone else does - look at the news story today regarding the hacked Xcode used in China - and that got through *with* approval.  Approval is fundamental to the app store workflow and I don't think that is ever going to change.  As I said, you can always host the content on your own server.

Comment: try the contentsync plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync

Comment: @ jcesarmobile ok thanks will try it